# How to add pagination button dynamically using 3rd party API data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am a new developer in web development and I am trying to create a simple game searcher web app using IGDB API. But I am not getting the point of how to dynamically add the page buttons. For example, If I search for Call of duty game there are many versions and the data that I get will be multiple, here how to implement the page number buttons. If the received data count is 40, how can I only display a certain amount on one page and remaining on the other and so on... Please help I'm stuck with this for a week now.

Comment: What type of page button do u need? Pagination button like 1,2,3 ?

Comment: Yes, I need exactly the page numbers if there are sufficient data that can overflow current page. And lets say we show only 20 items in a page for the sake of this question.

Comment: You can use `react-paginate` library. Refer the documentation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate